# Returning an empty array as false?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, boolean

I'm practicing functions and have written this code to print a boolean value if inStock is less than the weekly average. The code works for that purpose. The problem is, If the array is undefined I need it to return false. As it currently stands it cannot read the 'instock value' of undefined. If someone could point me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it.

```
let altInventory = [{
        candy: "Twizzlers",
        inStock: 180,
        weeklyAverage: 200
    },
    {
        candy: "Milk Duds",
        inStock: 300,
        weeklyAverage: 170
    },
]
// ===================================================

function findCandy(inv, cand) {
    for (let i = 0; i < inv.length; i++) {
        if (inv[i].candy === cand) {
            return inv[i];
        }
    }
}

function shouldWeOrderThisCandy(inv, cand) {
    let object = findCandy(inv, cand);
    if (object.inStock < object.weeklyAverage) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I've tried including this, but it doesn't seem to have an effect.

```
if (object.length === 0);
return false



//shouldWeOrderThisCandy(altInventory, "Milk Duds")
//shouldWeOrderThisCandy(altInventory, "Twizzlers")
shouldWeOrderThisCandy(altInventory, "Broccoli")
```

Comment: Tag with the language. There are many different languages with different rules. Also take some time to fix the indenting and show the _actual_ code, not a floating “I included this”.

Comment: Note that if `findCandy` does not find a candy, it doesn’t return anything and the result is `undefined` — not an empty object/array.

Comment: Ah, perfect. I see now. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
let altInventory = [
   { candy: "Twizzlers", inStock: 180, weeklyAverage: 200 },
   { candy: "Milk Duds", inStock: 300, weeklyAverage: 170 },
]; // Just in case you made a mistake, you need to put a semi-colon to end the statement.

function findCandy(inv, cand) {
   for (let i =0; i < inv.length; i++) {
      if (inv[i].candy === cand) { return inv[i]; }
   }
   return; // Have the function return at the end. You can make it return null or 0.
}

function shouldWeOrderThisCandy(inv, cand) {
   let object = findCandy(inv, cand);

   // since findCandy() now returns something, check if (object) so that it will work.
   if (object && object.inStock < object.weeklyAverage) { return true; }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Ensure to explain changes.

Comment: Ok I added comments to the snippets.

Comment: Note that all of these return the same value (`undefined`, which *is* a [special] value): `function f () { return undefined }`, `function f () { return }`, `function f () {}`. There is no "nothing" that can be assigned to an expression.

Answer (score 1):

undefined variables will evaluate as "falsey". So you could try something like:

```
if (object && object.inStock < object.weeklyAverage) {
```